# How many people fields are allowed on a PowerApps Form

Tags: people-picker, powerapp

I have a SharePoint Online list with 20 people fields. I am trying customize the list with PowerApps. Is there any limit on how many people picker I can have on the form?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint has a soft limit of 12 lookup columns (which includes People columns) per list. When you exceed this limit you'll start getting the following error message when you try to retrieve items from the list, "The query cannot be completed because the number of lookup columns it contains exceeds the lookup column threshold."

I don't have a lot of experience with Power Apps, but my guess is that this limit will cause you problems if you try to customize the list forms with Power Apps.

[image: Lookup column threshold error.]

Answer (score 0):

**There is no restriction placed upon field counts in PowerApps forms**

I have a similar form and can confidently state that no such restrictions exist. People pickers are essentially just Data Cards in Power Apps, thus they are regulated as such. Here is a double check of my statement with a post on the PowerUsers Forum.

https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/PowerApps-maximum-number-of-data-card-in-form/td-p/142960

Comment: I added 15 people pickers on the powerapps form and it's doesn't want to publish. no errors is given. I have another form which has 30 fields but they are all different type. My question is related to having more than 12 people picker (lookup fields) on powerapps form.

Comment: Try File / Save and then Publish. It happens when a form is overloaded.

Comment: It finally published after I deleted old form and created a new one. I have all people controls (more than 12) on the form. when i test the form i get this error on open and on save.

The requested operation is invalid. Server Response: Test failed: The query cannot be completed because the number of lookup columns it contains exceeds the lookup column threshold. clientRequestId: 67f9341b-07d9-4129-bdcc-02f837503ea1 serviceRequestId: 67f9341b-07d9-4129-bdcc-02f837503ea1

Comment: I added the print shot to my op (original post) so you can see it.

Comment: Ah I see, you have a SharePoint Connection to the app. Despite PowerApps having no field restrictions, SharePoint lists do and as the gentleman above pointed out it is 12 columns. I was under the impression we were discussing a form in a standalone app, excuse me.